# What RDP program would you recommend as a KVM replacement (with drive sharing) but separate screens?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, virtual-keyboard

I am looking for a Windows 10 compatible RDP program (i.e. not X11/VNC based) to allow one laptop to act as a KVM for another.  (I looked at the list of RDP software on Wikipedia, but most seemed to be VNC clones and last I checked Windows 10's desktop is not X11 based although you can run VcXserve on top of it for some applications like Emacs.)

I have two Windows 10 laptops side-by-side (but one with a semi-broken keyboard, it works, but sometimes you have to push certain keys more than once for them to register, so I am willing to boot it and type in my password, but don't want to use it for actual typing).

So, I would like to use an RDP program to allow the first one to be used as a keyboard/mouse for the other, but I want both screens to be used.  The standard windows RDP utility, closes the screen on the laptop being controlled, showing instead the splash screen.  I want two screens, one per laptop, two separate OSes, etc (but would prefer some level of file sharing, although I can live with that being done separately).

I would prefer an Open Source program but am willing to buy commercial software if it has licenses for personal (non-commercial) use within my budget.

Comment: Well, there's Dameware and some free VNCs, but why not just purchase a USB keyboard and use that? I have a similar situation where a laptop is slowly dying and the keyboard is one of the many problems, but I'm using it with a USB keyboard plugged into the working USB port.

Comment: I haven't found a USB keyboard with the little mouse button (the "pointer stick") between the ghb keys (and I've been looking for one like that for some 15-20 years).  If I do, I will switch to that, but even then I will have two keyboards and not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a true RDP program, but since you're using Windows, you may want to look into the [Microsoft Garage project called "Mouse without Borders"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460). This allows you to control up to four computers on a network with a single mouse and keyboard; you can also copy and paste data between them.

Comment: This looks close enough to what I want.  I will try it.  If it works, you are my answer!  Thank you.  (And by the way, in the end I will probably have 4 computers, so it even has the right limits...

Comment: By the way, to get the connectivity I wanted for directories, I simply use the Windows native ability to export and import directories across the network rather than the cut and paste facility provided in "Mouse withou Borders".

Comment: That's OK for files, but if I understand it correctly, it's actually sharing the clipboard in such a way that you could also e.g., take a screen shot from one monitor and paste it into  Paint or CorelDRAW! or whatever running on a different computer.